# overlaying two plots, one with flipped coordinates, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay two similar graphs, but one with "flipped coordinates", on top of each other.

I want to draw "best response" functions of a symmetric problem. So I have the same data frame  for the two graphs, just that one needs to be flipped.

adding `coord_flip()` will flip coordinates for "both graphs".

Consider the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  x=c(0.000, 0.111, 0.222, 0.333, 0.444, 0.556, 0.667, 0.778, 0.889, 1.000),
  y=c(0.222, 0.111, 0.111, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000, 0.889, 0.889, 0.778)
  )
```

I would like to do this graph, where the red line is just the black line flipped:

[image: desired result]

The following code

```
ggplot(df1)+ 
  geom_line(aes(x,y),color="black")+
  geom_line(aes(y,x),color="red")
```

Results in this, which is not what I'm looking for.

[image: actual result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line` for the flipped line, after sorting your dataset's rows in the desired order. From `?geom_path`:

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they
>   appear in the data. `geom_line()` connects them in order of the
>   variable on the x axis.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  arrange(x, y) %>%
  ggplot()+ 
  geom_line(aes(x, y), color = "black")+
  geom_path(aes(y, x), color = "red")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 8, by = 2),
              y = seq(30, 15, by = -5))

ggplot(df1)+ 
geom_line(aes(x,log(y)),color="black")+
geom_line(aes(log(y),x),color="red")
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This does not do the job I want because it does not connect the points properly (in another example I'm working on). What I need is to actually flip the graph. Not sure if this is clear enough or I should write a more complete question.

Comment: It seems to me that Andrew's answer is appropriate for the question you've posted, so if your problem is more detailed than this, perhaps you could include some of that detail in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Does the `geom_line(aes(log(y),x),color="red")` not result in a `coord_flip()`?

Comment: I have changed the question to show what I'm really trying to do. Sorry for not being clear.